# Why VIEW SOURCE does not show populated dropdownlistboxes?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

The code below works well in terms of getting the two dropdownlistboxes populated dynamically.

First, there is the getBuildings function that makes a call to getBuildings.php file.

This populates the buildingID dropdownlistbox.

This works fine.

Then there is the getFloors function that makes a call to getFloors.php file and populates the floor dropdownlistbox based on selection from buildingID dropdownlistbox.

This works fine as well.

My issue is that when I right-click the page to view source, I expected to see atleast the buildingID dropdownlist populated with values from the database but I don't.

What am I missing?

Here is the working code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        getBuildings();

        $('#buildingID').change(function() {
            getFloors( $(this).val() );
        });
    });


    function getBuildings() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'getBuild.php',
            dataType: 'json'
        })
        .done(function(buildingInfo) {
            $(buildingInfo).each(function(i, building) {
                $('<option>').val(building.BuildingID).text(building.BuildingDisplay).appendTo( $('#buildingID') );
            })
        });
    }


    function getFloors(buildingID) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'getRevisions.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { buildingID: buildingID }
        })
        .done(function(floorInfo) {
            $(floorInfo).each(function(i, floor) {
                $('<option>').val(floor.FloorDisplay).text(floor.FloorDisplay).appendTo( $('#floor') );
            })
        });
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <form name="reqform" method='POST' action='processRequest.php'>
    <p>
       <div class="side-by-side clearfix">
        <div>
          <select name="buildingID" id="buildingID" data-placeholder="Choose a building..." class="chosen-select" style="width:600px;font-size:12pt;">
            <option value="">Choose a building...</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div>
          <select name="floor" id="floor" data-placeholder="Choose a floor..." class="chosen-select" style="width:600px;font-size:12pt;">
            <option value="">Choose a floor...</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div data-role="content">
          <input type="text" name="room" id="room" value="  Enter a room..." onfocus="clearText(this)" onblur="restoreText(this)" style="width:593px;color:#999;font-size:9pt;height:20px;">
        </div>
      </div>
    </p>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are missing the point of AJAX. You should check generated source with FireBug or DEV Tools on Chrome, what you see on right click and view source is the initial state of HTML page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The source code is the *source* code (the raw HTML document delivered to the browser), not a serialisation of the DOM after it has been manipulated by JavaScript.

If you want to see that, use a DOM Inspector (most browsers have one built into the developer tools these days).

Comment: et al, thank you all for the insight.

This explains why dropdown in the link below with Autocomplete doesn't work for me.

http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

It works if values in dropdown are manually populated.

Answer (score 2):

The `View source` feature presents only what hes been outputed by the server to the browser. Your dropdowns are build dynamically on client-side.

To investigate what hes been build by JavaScript use tools like [FireBug](https://addons.mozilla.org/pl/firefox/addon/firebug/) or the debug console in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, cause you are populating them using javascript.

Comment: There are several techniques you can use with client-side JavaScript that can adjust the actual source of the page.  Not especially efficient techniques, mind you, but "because JavaScript" isn't the answer.

Comment: @DougM Right, but not the one he is using.

Comment: Well, @MillaresRoo, the real source of my misery is being asked to add AutomComplete to the dropdowns and to specifically the one from the link above.

No way to make that happen given the way my code is written.